# How can I change the Job Queue processing in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.1, job-queue

I have three jobs in my queue;

- A
- B
- C

Retry count for one of them is set to 100.

When all my jobs are failing, Laravel runs the jobs as following scheme;

- A 1
- B 1
- C 1

and then;

- A 2
- B 2
- C 2

I want to change this behavior as the following scheme;

- A 100 (to failed table)
- B 1
- C 0

So I want the previous jobs to be blocking tikk they reach their retry counts and then continue to the next job.

How can I achieve this with Laravel’s Job system?

( I can’t chain the jobs on my software layer with chain method. I would like to achieve this by configuration )

Comment: if things are to be done synchronously then why put them as a job?

Comment: Because I didn’t code the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a job you cannot control another job from that one... Jobs are working asynchronously. You need to get things done synchronously :)

So or you move everything into one job, or you cannot do it in another way :)

Of course, you can name your queues, and run with prioritizing them and setup only 1 worker... But this isn't a good option and you cannot be good with that :)

---

Also, you can fire job after one job is done. Just move creating a job from your controller(?) into the job after the finish. I have that solution implemented in my own system. Only if one job is done, then next is firing

Comment: I guess there isn't any way to run the jobs sequentially as you pointed out. I will use your answer and implement my own architecture. Every job will get the next job from a `passive jobs table` and add it to the job queue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Job Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#job-events) to control the sequence in which they are pushed on to a queue. Once job A successfully finishes, Job B starts via an event listener, same for Job C. Job A can retry 100 times with no way of triggering Job B.